# ActionHandler in jbpm7?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, redhat-bpm

I am migrating my jbpm framework from 3 to 7.
I want to migrate the actionHandlers there.
Can anyone help me with the equivalent of ActionHandler(from jbpm 3) to jbpm7?
Also how can I make it execute when a node is completed?
JBPM3 has this xml based injection of beans which was very clear. it seems confusing now?
Is it possible via api or xml?
Tried WorkItemHandler, but didnot get a breakthrough with that.